# ASP.NET Razor Pages - Conditional redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In one of my EF entities, I have a boolean field that indicates whether there is or not a maintainance going.

Thus, I would like to reroute all my pages to a 503 error page only if this boolean is set to true.

I could put the following piece of code in every Page:

```
if (_context.SystemParameters.First().Maintenance)
    return Redirect("/Error/503");
```

But this wouldn't be straightforward at all. Is there a best way to achieve such a conditional redirection on all my pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved with a simple custom [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#write-middleware) component, which would allow for performing the required logic before even entering the MVC pipeline. Here's an example implementation:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    var context = ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourContext>();

    if (ctx.Request.Path != "/Error/503" && context.SystemParameters.First().Maintenance)
    {
        ctx.Response.Redirect("/Error/503");
        return;
    }

    await next();
});
```

Here, `ctx` is an instance of `HttpContext`, which is used first to retrieve an instance of `YourContext` from the DI container and second to perform a redirect. If `Maintenance` is `false`, `next` is invoked in order to pass execution on to the next middleware component.

This call to `Use` would go before `UseMvc` in the `Startup.Configure` method in order to allow for short-circuiting the middleware pipeline. Note that this approach would apply to controllers/views as well as to Razor Pages - it could also be placed further up in the `Configure` method if there is other middleware that you would want to avoid in the case of being in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a PageFilter. If you want this on all your pages maybe implement an IPageFilter or IAsyncPageFilter and register it globally.
I think that you can check https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters if you need more details